# highchart : Add the series name on the column chart

Tags: highcharts

I need to have the series name printed on each column. Right now you can only print the value of the column as a label. http://jsfiddle.net/mVxGz/

Any ideas on how to do that?

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                align: 'left',
                enabled: true,
                rotation: 270,
                inside: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via the [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.formatter). For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/mVxGz/1/):

```
            formatter: function () {
                return this.series.name + ' - ' + this.y;
            }
```

Comment: that works for tooltip, I tried this and no change:     plotOptions: {
     series: {
      dataLabels: {
       align: 'left',
       enabled: true,
       rotation: 270,
       inside: true
      }
     },
     formatter: function () {
                 return this.series.name + ' - ' + this.y;
             }
   },

Comment: Working on the jsFiddle example. What are you expected results? I am seeing 'Jane - 3' on the Apples category data label.

Comment: Note that your tooltip is busted. Error `this.x.toLowerCase()` is not a function.

Comment: can you please paste the exact code or update the jsFiddle and send me link ?